# Reading numbers on a line

Tags: java

I have taken an input from stdin. This input will be a line of several numbers. For example a valid value for the variable line will be :

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I know how many numbers there will be and I've stored this in the variable N. I am trying to store these numbers in an array of size N.

```
String a="";
for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
    if(line.charAt(i)!=' ')
        a = a+ line.charAt(i);
    else{
        numbers[x++]=Integer.parseInt(a);
        a="";
    }
}
numbers[x]=Integer.parseInt(a); //to store the last number in the array
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String your_number_string;
String[] numbers = your_number_string.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String#split`:

```
String[] numbersAsString = line.split(" ");  // one space, right?
Listy<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();  // lists are better here
for (String numberAsString:numbersAsString) {
  try {
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(numberAsString));
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // input was not a number is not added to the list
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.split()` to separate inputs.

[Check this.](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/string-split-example-in-java-tutorial.html)

```
String input = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
String[] splits = input.split(" ");

for(String num : splits){    
    if (num != null && num.trim() != "") {
        try {
            numbers[x++] = Integer.parseInt(num);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In any case it's more efficient to use a `StringBuilder#append()` to concatenate your Characters, instead of calling repeatedly `a = a+`